# How to use/integrate spring security from an older version of spring mvc 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I was tasked to assign to modify an application with RBAC(Role Based access control) for a project which uses an older spring mvc version 3.0.5.

We plan to integrate spring security for this task.

The question is, are there any older version of spring security we can use 
that is compatible with the spring mvc we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last ***[Spring Security-3.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.6.RELEASE)*** supports **spring 3.0.6**. This version of spring security should work fine for your project.

Although your version should work fine with this version of spring security if you want you can do a minor version upgrade of spring. You can find the changelogs here https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/24/spring-3-0-6-is-now-available

And documentation for this version of the library can be found at this link [spring-security-3.0.7-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/springsecurity-single.html)

> But, please be cautious, it's not recommended to use older versions of security-related libraries since they might have known vulnerabilities.

Comment: thanks, does it mean that I need to upgrade from spring 3.0.5 to spring 3.0.6? what would be its implications?

Comment: This is a minor release and should not have any breaking change. It is mostly a bugfix release.

Comment: @Chizbox you can find the changelogs here https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/24/spring-3-0-6-is-now-available

Comment: thanks again mate, now I have to ask on what version of spring mvc  can I upgrade at most with no code changes?

Comment: Since you are using spring 3.0.5 the minimum or next hop is 3.0.6 this is the minimum version you have to upgrade. But what the most recent version that you can upgrade without code change will largely depend on your code base. You can read this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035908/upgrading-large-application-from-spring-3-0-x-to-4-1-x-what-best-practices-p