# How do I upgrade Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar

I am currently at `Spring 2.5`, I want to upgrade it to `4.3.2`.
The way I am doing it is downloading the jar files from https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.3.2.RELEASE/
, extracting it getting the JAR files, and replace the files with the same name with the old ones. But the problem is there are a lot of JARs that are not previously in the old version, should I add all the new JAR files to the `lib`?
Are there anything else I should do besides replacing the JARs and changing the xsd versions in `application-context.xml` and also upgrading other libraries that are compatible with the new spring version?

I know using Maven will make it a lot easier, but that is currently off the table, thank you.

Comment: Upgrading a Spring version is not an easy task and is not about changing the version of your dependencies. You should take in consideration that, after migrating your code, you will deal with some broken code and compatibility issues. Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035908/upgrading-large-application-from-spring-3-0-x-to-4-1-x-what-best-practices-p https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-a-legacy-spring-application-to-a-spring https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x

Comment: Don't upgrade in 1 go. See https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-06-21-Upgrade-Spring-Framework-In-Existing-Application/ for an upgrade path (there are more ways but this is what I tent to use).